# Error with doctrine mapping import

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to import a database already created for another project (not a symfony one), so I can use it inside a symfony project.

Validation works
    php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
    [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
    [Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

But when I make `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle annotation` it return

> In MappingException.php line 588:
>   It is not possible to map entity 'Tprovincia' with a composite primary
>   key as part of the primary key of another entity 'Tlocalidad#paiscod'.

This is de configuration of those tables

```
CREATE TABLE tprovincia
(
  paiscod smallint NOT NULL, -- Código de país
  procod smallint NOT NULL, -- Código de provincia
  prodes character varying(100) NOT NULL, -- Nombre de provincia
  prodesamp character varying(250) NOT NULL, -- Descripción ampliada de provincia
  prousupro character varying(30) NOT NULL, -- Pro Usu Pro
  profecpro timestamp without time zone NOT NULL, -- Pro Fec Pro
  CONSTRAINT tprovincia_pkey PRIMARY KEY (paiscod, procod),
  CONSTRAINT itprovincia1 FOREIGN KEY (paiscod)
      REFERENCES tpais (paiscod) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE tlocalidad
(
  paiscod smallint NOT NULL, -- Código de país
  procod smallint NOT NULL, -- Código de provincia
  loccod integer NOT NULL, -- Código de localidad
  locdes character varying(100) NOT NULL, -- Descripción de localidad
  loccodpos character(8) NOT NULL, -- Código postal localidad
  locusupro character varying(30) NOT NULL, -- Loc Usu Pro
  locfecpro timestamp without time zone NOT NULL, -- Loc Fec Pro
  CONSTRAINT tlocalidad_pkey PRIMARY KEY (paiscod, procod, loccod),
  CONSTRAINT itlocalidad1 FOREIGN KEY (paiscod, procod)
      REFERENCES tprovincia (paiscod, procod) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

One more thing, the database is a postgreSQL one.
Hope someone can help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the composite primary keys defined here:

```
CONSTRAINT tprovincia_pkey PRIMARY KEY (paiscod, procod)
```

and here:

```
CONSTRAINT tlocalidad_pkey PRIMARY KEY (paiscod, procod, loccod)
```

What you could do is modify your database a little bit to use a more typical single id field as primary key (you can keep the old key with a UNIQUE index to have something that is close to a primary key) and then reference that as foreign key.

Comment: I can't modify the DB

Comment: In that case you probably will not be able to let Doctrine manage the Relationship. Instead you have to do it manually. Basically, instead of defining a relationship like `@ORM\ManyToOne()` you just define the column `@Column(name="paiscod")` and then probably handle this in your custom repository class.